# Terminal shortcut to SUPER key

Tags: shortcut-keys

I would like to use the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to launch the terminal in Ubuntu 14.04.2

I installed compizconfig settings manager, removed the <kbd>Super</kbd> binding from launching the dash.

In compiz I cannot find a keybind for the terminal. I tried to set a command with `gnome-terminal` and bind it to super, but it doesn't work.

I tried to use the now free super key as a standard key bind to the terminal in the `settings > keyboard > shortcuts` but it simply doesn't accept the key as a binding.

How can I do this? thanks!

Comment: Ok, in 15.04 I can bind "Super L" and "Super R". Don't know if it depends on the version of Ubuntu. You have a keyboard with just a "Super" key. I don't think I can help, because I don't have such hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to do this, because I wanted to use `dmenu` instead of the dash, and wanted to have it bound to the same key as dash was before.

There is no easy way to bind a modifier key (<kbd>Super</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>) to a custom command, I think this is intentional (because it causes problems when other key bindings include the remapped modifier).

The only way that I think you can do it is by changing super to be a normal key (for example with `xmodmap`), however you will no longer be able to use it as a modifier and it may break other shortcuts.